# Wrapper stopped in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I am Working on Sonarqube 6.7. In that I tried to add a plugin in the extensions after adding that it is not running and it shows the following error. It shows that wrapper stopped after adding the plugin. And sometimes it shows that the **file is not a plugin delete it and restart it**.

> 2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.AbstractByteBuf] -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
>   2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory] Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@177afe77
>   2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 32768
>   2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
>   2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
>   2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
>   2018.01.23 17:31:37 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] connected to node [{sonarqube}{Ffns-XbVS1-gA83eULUN0g}{es2zUZIqQWCKYmVDGeqolg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube}]
>   2018.01.23 17:31:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
>   2018.01.23 17:31:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\Development_Avecto\Sonar\sonarqube-6.7\temp\sq-process2260223316073485817properties
>   2018.01.23 17:32:02 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [web]: 0
>   2018.01.23 17:32:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
>   2018.01.23 17:32:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
>   2018.01.23 17:32:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
>   2018.01.23 17:32:03 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{SLYBSoBGT7uXhxJ_uZYkoQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}], ignoring...
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9001] connect_timeout[30s]
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:362)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:570)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:117)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:351)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:407)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:357)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$ScheduledNodeSampler.run(TransportClientNodesService.java:390)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9001
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:352)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:632)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
>       ... 1 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>       ... 10 common frames omitted
>   <-- Wrapper Stopped

Comment: How did you stop SonarQube? Check if there are still Java processes running. Check also if some other program is using port 9001.

Comment: No other program using that port. n other java processes are running i checked but still it is coming like that

Comment: could you check logs/es.log and logs/ce.log please ?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

use java 11.0.5 for set environment variable in your computer